# Please getting this error fileUpload() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request when trying to upload an image

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-7

**Argument 1 passed to App\Candidate::fileUpload() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel-voting-system\app\Candidate.php on line 40**

please I don't know where am getting it wrong 
[this is where I wrote the fill upload function(candidate.php)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPnHp.png)

[The second image is the downward path of the same folder candidate.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZnvX.png)

**this my user.php for your view**

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','regno'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }

    public function candidate(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Candidate');
    }

    public function registerVoter($name,$email,$password,$regno){
        $newVoter = new User;
        $newVoter->name = $name;
        $newVoter->email = $email;
        $newVoter->password = bcrypt($password);
        $newVoter->regno = $regno;
        $newVoter->role_id = 2;
        $newVoter->save();
    }
    public static function addCandidate($studentId,$seat,$image){
        $user = User::find($studentId);
        (new Candidate)->add($user->name,$seat,$user->regno,$user->id,$image,);
    }
```

**And my AdminController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','regno'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }

    public function candidate(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Candidate');
    }

    public function registerVoter($name,$email,$password,$regno){
        $newVoter = new User;
        $newVoter->name = $name;
        $newVoter->email = $email;
        $newVoter->password = bcrypt($password);
        $newVoter->regno = $regno;
        $newVoter->role_id = 2;
        $newVoter->save();
    }
    public static function addCandidate($studentId,$seat,$image){
        $user = User::find($studentId);
        (new Candidate)->add($user->name,$seat,$user->regno,$user->id,$image,);
    }
```

I really appreciate your efforts, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Both AdminController and User are same in your question. Copy/paste problem.

Comment: Try to add App\Http\Requests; before your class or https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191895/10634638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've mixed a controller with a model.

See, the controller is meant to handle the request. The model is meant to persist entities and handle their relationships. Your `Candidate` is neither.

Laravel has a type hinting system that will inject an instance of the hinted type in the controller method automagically. Therefore, if you had a controller in the likes of

```
<?php
 use  Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class CandidateController {

    public function fileUpload( Request $request ) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

And a route in the likes of

```
Route::post('candidate','CandidateController@fileUpload');
```

Then `fileUpload` method would receive an instance of `\Illuminate\Http\Request`

Now, if you submitted a file from the frontend, the file would be in the request (as shown in your code)

```
$image = $request->file('image');  // 'image' is just the input name
```

So you should not call `fileUpload` from another method. It's the other way around. The frontend sends the request, the controller handles the request and "extracts" the file which would then be persisted in the disk/cloud/wherever and its metadata sent to the DDBB and associated to the acting user

The controller moves the image (you're already doing that) to its intended path, then stores it in the model like

```
  public function fileUpload( Request $request ) {

    $image = $request->file('image');  

    $candidate = new App\Candidate();

    $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalName();

    $image->move(public_path("images"), $name);
    $candidate->path = public_path('images').'/'.$name;
    $candidate->save();
  }
```

Since there are other fields, I guess you are sending them in the request too, like

```
    $candidate->seat = $request->seat;
```

And the acting user, if you need it, should come from the auth helper (e.g. the session or token) to avoid a malicious visitor sending another user's id.

Comment: I am so grateful. You mean I should remove the Fileupload function from the model and create a new controller for it. Please what if I add to my AdminController will it work?

Comment: Check the comment on your question: you repeated your model code where your controller was supposed to be. Anyway, the fileUpload method should go in a controller and be implicitly invoked by a route, not by another method (unless said method has access to the request itself)

Comment: Thanks a lot, at least it obvious that am just setting my feet strong in Laravel with the way you see my code really appreciate. I am working on that now.